# Can the MailCore2 framework connect to an Exchange server

Tags: mailcore2

Is it possible to connect to an Exchange server using the MailCore2 framework? The documentation does not discuss Exchange Server support.

I want to build my own email client which can connect to the Exchange Server and replace Outlook. Can I use the MailCore2 framework?

Comment: It doesn't support exchange server for now. Also, be careful, you need to license a Microsoft patent to be able to implement exchange server protocol.

Comment: Thank you very much Dinh Viêt Hoà.

Answer (score 0):

If your Exchange server has enabled IMAP support, you can connect to the Exchange server using IMAP with MailCore2. This does not require any licence from Microsoft.